# Gradle upgrade to version 6.2.1 issues

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm having problems upgrading my Gradle to version 6.2.1 I'm currently running android studio 3.6.1 I'm trying to do this because I kept getting an error that says Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 4.10.2.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.2.1/gradle-6.2.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.2.1/gradle-6.2.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Facing same issue with latest android studio 3.6 1 with error Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1.

Comment: what repo are using to download gradle ?? add those :        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google() 2.try changing gradle version to 6.5.1